# Input to make "Enter" forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML input in my site and i want to make "ENTER" forbidden in this box.

I mean user should not be able to enter into the box and if the user pasted some text, the enters gets converted to "space character" auto.

Comment: Make the box `readonly` or `disabled` according to your intent.

Comment: <input> tags are single-line. Are you sure you're not using a <textarea>?

Comment: @acbabis How can i do if i want for textarea ?

Comment: check my answer, the one you have accepted does not prevent all cases of line-breaks from happening, and my answer will prevent all cases of line-breaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

</script>
```

Comment: this won't stop the user from pasting page-breaks/line-breaks

Answer (score 1):

you can put this in the onchange of the text input/textarea

```
var text = document.forms[0].txt.value;
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');|
```

put this inside your header script tags and you should be good.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() { 
        var txts = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA') 

        for(var i = 0, l = txts.length; i < l; i++) {
          var func = function() { 


              var text = this.value;
              text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');
              this.value = text;
            } 
          txts[i].onkeyup = func;
          txts[i].onblur = func;
          }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

```
<input type='text' id='text'>

var timer = null;
$('#text').keydown(function(){
       clearTimeout(timer); 
       timer = setTimeout(doStuff, 1000)
});

function doStuff() {
    alert('do stuff');
}
```

use the `doStuff()` function to execute code 1 second after user stops typing